# palindrome of number in C

Tags: c, while-loop, numbers, palindrome

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int rev=0,temp=0,frwd,n,ans=0;
 int i,j;
    for(i=100;i<=999;i++)
    {   
        for(j=i;j<=999;j++)
        {
            n = i*j;
        frwd = n;
        while(n!=0)
        {   

            temp = n%10;
            n = n/10;
            rev = temp+rev*10;

        }       
        printf("%d",rev);       
        if((rev == frwd)&&(ans<frwd))
        {
            ans=frwd;
            printf("%d",ans);
        }
        }
    }
return(0);
}
```

I have tried working out everything but this code doesn't seem to give the correct output.
The desired output is largest palindrome number of 6 digits.
If I am running the individual parts i.e. the reversing of number , checking of number whether or not it is a palindrome or the for loops, they are working fine but in the program they are giving garbage as output.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What debugging have you attempted so far?

Comment: The largest 6-digit palindrome is `999999`, right?  Why do you need the program?

Comment: Problem is with initialization of `rev`. You have reinitialize it each time. Try adding `rev = 0;` in the inner `for` loop. Do you need to check the max of all these palindromes? Or as @CarlNorum has pointed it is `999999`

Comment: Also, you can just run to loop from 100000 to 999999, if you want to generate all the 6 digit palindrome. Using a product as you have done does not generate all the 6 digit numbers (like 100001 etc)

Comment: Are you trying to solve [Project Euler problem #4](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4)?

Comment: @CarlNorum I have to find the largest palindrome which will result from multiplication of 2 3 digit number, so 999999 is not an answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have tried running each part of the programming separately and they all look to give out put fine.
Well I am not familiar with GDB nd it's functioning i was nt able to use it

Answer (score 2):

ya the problem is that you are not reinitializing rev to 0 as said by cowanother.anon.ard. Try putting rev=0 in inner for loop.

But you cant get 999999 as the highest palindrome number of 6 digit by your method as u r not checking all the 6 digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int rev=0,temp=0,frwd,n,ans=0;
int i,j;
for(i=100000;i<=999999;i++)
{

    frwd = n = i;
    rev = 0;
    while(n!=0)
    {

        temp = n%10;
        n = n/10;
        rev = temp+rev*10;

    }
    if((rev == frwd)&&(ans<frwd))
    {
        ans=frwd;
    }

}
printf("%d\n",ans);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: As i have pointed put earlier this code is not of any use to me. I have to find the product palindrome not just some 6 digit palindrome.Thanks anyways!!

Answer (score 1):

4 problems with your Code:-

1. Like another.anon.coward said- you need to put `rev=0` inside inner loop
2. You need to separate each number printed either by a space or a newline ('\n')
   `printf("\n %d");`. Otherwise they will look like one big number (garbage).
3. Your algorithm is also wrong. According to your program, the largest 6-digit number is 906609 (The correct answer is 999999). For this you should change your inner loop to `j=0;j<999;j++` and change `n=i*j` to `n=i*1000+j`.
4. Also move the `printf("\n%d",ans);` outside the loop.

The corrected program is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
     int rev=0,temp=0,frwd,n,ans=0;
     int i,j;
    for(i=100;i<=999;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<=999;j++) /*CORRECTED THIS LINE,*/
        {   rev=0;/*ADDED THIS LINE;*/
            n = (i*1000) + j; /*CORRECTED THIS LINE*/
            frwd = n;
            while(n!=0)
            {   

                temp = n%10;
                n = n/10;
                rev = temp+rev*10;

            }       
            printf("\n%d",rev); /*THIS  LINE,*/
            if((rev == frwd)&&(ans<frwd))
            {
                ans=frwd;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d",ans); /* AND THIS LINE*/

    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: why 2 loops? In this method there is wastage of computation time. So loop from 100000 to 999999.

Comment: Just sticking to his logic, so that he can figure out where he went wrong. He can learn to improve performance later.

Comment: It kinda looks like the problem was misstated, and that the OP has to find the largest palindrome that's a product of two integers.  Course, since he didn't actually *ask* that yet, this answer is still as correct as any other...

Comment: This program will give output 999999 which is not the desired output as i cannot produce this number by multiplying two 3 digit numbers.Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int rev=0,temp=0,frwd,n,ans=0;
 int i,j;
for(i=100;i<=999;i++)
{   
    for(j=0;j<=999;j++) /*CORRECTED THIS LINE,*/
    {   rev=0;/*ADDED THIS LINE;*/
        n = (i*1000) + j; /*CORRECTED THIS LINE*/
        frwd = n;
        while(n!=0)
        {   

            temp = n%10;
            n = n/10;
            rev = temp+rev*10;

        }       
        printf("\n%d",rev); /*THIS  LINE,*/
        if((rev == frwd)&&(ans<frwd))
        {
            ans=frwd;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n%d",ans); /* AND THIS LINE*/

return(0);
}
```